# Как можно присвоить одинаковое значение к списку переменных в Terraform

Tags: переменные, terraform, ci-cd

Если этот эквивалент присвоения одинакового значения к переменным?

```
var1 = value
var2 = value
var3 = value
```

```
var1 = var2 = var3 = value
```